# “ indirect fixture” error using pytest. What is wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, python-3.7

```
 def fatorial(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n*fatorial(n - 1)


import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("entrada","esperado",[
    (0,1),
    (1,1),
    (2,2),
    (3,6),
    (4,24),
    (5,120)
])

def testa_fatorial(entrada,esperado):
    assert fatorial(entrada)  == esperado
```

The error:

```
 ERROR collecting Fatorial_pytest.py ____________________________________________________________________
In testa_fatorial: indirect fixture '(0, 1)' doesn't exist
```

I dont know why I got "indirect fixture”. Any idea?
I am using python 3.7 and windows 10 64 bits.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

***TL;DR*** -
The problem is with the line

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("entrada","esperado",[ ... ])
```

It should be written as a comma-separated string:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("entrada, esperado",[ ... ])
```

---

You got the `indirect fixture` because pytest couldn't unpack the given `argvalues` since it got a wrong `argnames` parameter. You need to make sure all parameters are written as one string.

Please see the [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-mark-parametrize-ref):

> The builtin pytest.mark.parametrize decorator enables parametrization of arguments for a test function.
>
> Parameters:
>   1. ***argnames*** – a comma-separated string denoting one or more argument names,  or a list/tuple of argument strings.
>   2. ***argvalues*** – The list of argvalues determines how often a test is invoked
>   with different argument values.

Meaning, you should write the arguments you want to parametrize as a single string and separate them using a comma. Therefore, your test should look like this:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("n, expected", [
    (0, 1),
    (1, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 6),
    (4, 24),
    (5, 120)
])
def test_factorial(n, expected):
    assert factorial(n) == expected
```

Comment: Anyone has any guess what's the source of that incredibly misleading error?

Comment: TL;DR is an insane time-saver, nice

Comment: Cool, this is the answer

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar error from omitting the square brackets around the parameter values, e.g.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('task_status', State.PENDING,
                                         State.PROCESSED,
                                         State.FAILED)
```

Gives the error 'indirect fixture 'P' doesn't exist'. The fix:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('task_status', [State.PENDING,
                                         State.PROCESSED,
                                         State.FAILED])
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who ends up here for the same reason I did, if you're labeling your tests with a list of ids, the ids list must be a *named* parameter like so:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("arg1, arg2", paramlist, ids=param_ids)
```

instead of

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("arg1, arg2", paramlist, param_ids)
```